# If Statement in SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

I have a query that give me multiple result like this ones:

```
|DATE|------|DESCRIPTION|---|PDV|----------|ID|-------|NAME|--------|Value|-|Quantity|
2016-01-25    DESAYUNOS     REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
2016-01-25    COMIDAS       REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
2016-01-25    CENAS         REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
2016-01-25    DESAYUNOS     REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[CHEQUES].Fecha,  
    [dbo].[TURNOS].Descripcion, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Pla AS Platillo_Id, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Descripcion, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Pre AS PrecioPlatillo, 
    [dbo].[CAPMO].Can AS CantidadPlatillo
FROM         
    [dbo].[CAPMO] 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[CHEQUES] ON [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV = [dbo].[CHEQUES].Cla_PDV 
                    AND [dbo].[CAPMO].Che = [dbo].[CHEQUES].Che 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[PLATILLOS] ON [dbo].[CAPMO].Pla = [dbo].PLATILLOS].Pla 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[TURNOS] ON [dbo].[CAPMO].Clave_PDV = [dbo].[TURNOS].Clave_PDV
WHERE     
    ([dbo].[CHEQUES].St = 'P') AND ([dbo].[CAPMO].Stpl = 'A')
```

Line 1 and 4 are exactly the same, is there a query that can detect same rows an increase the |Quantity| Column by 1 for each equals?
like and If statemnt with a while i don tknow if this is posible in SQL

Im looking for an output like this:

```
|DATE|------|DESCRIPTION|---|PDV|----------|ID|-------|NAME|--------|Value|-|Quantity|

2016-01-25    COMIDAS       REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
2016-01-25    CENAS         REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    1
2016-01-25    DESAYUNOS     REST            1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00    2
```

Comment: Provide DBMS (*MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc...*)

Comment: Quantity Always equal to 1?

Comment: No the query takes the  value quantity from datatabse, but i would like to increase if a rows its the same by 1, i just edited my full query atm, is there a way to do this?
@StanislovasKalašnikovas

Comment: Not in that sense, but there are many tricks that can solve it for you - group by/count and/or sum over ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *SQL-Server* you can use `ROW_NUMBER` in following:

**QUERY**

```
select [date], [description], pdv, id, name, value, 
       case when rn > 1 then quantity+rn-1 else quantity end as quantity
from( 
    select *, 
           row_number() over(partition by [date], [description], pdv, id, name, value, quantity order by [date]) rn 
    from #t
)x
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #t
(
    [date] date,
    [description] nvarchar(60),
    pdv nvarchar(60),
    id int,
    name nvarchar(60),
    value nvarchar(60),
    quantity int
)
insert into #t values
 ('2016-01-25','DESAYUNOS','REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
,('2016-01-25','COMIDAS'  ,'REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
,('2016-01-25','CENAS'    ,'REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
,('2016-01-25','DESAYUNOS','REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
,('2016-01-25','DESAYUNOS','REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
,('2016-01-25','DESAYUNOS','REST',1,'DEL PATRON COMBO','162.00',1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
date        description pdv     id  name                value   quantity
2016-01-25  CENAS       REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  1
2016-01-25  COMIDAS     REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  1
2016-01-25  DESAYUNOS   REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  1
2016-01-25  DESAYUNOS   REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  2
2016-01-25  DESAYUNOS   REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  3
2016-01-25  DESAYUNOS   REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  4
```

Take a look at this part `quantity+rn-1` It will increase each duplicate row by 1 even if you have more duplicates than 2.

If you want only increase by 1 not depending on how many duplicates are use `quantity-1` instead of `quantity+rn-1`.

**UPDATE**

If you want to get result without duplicates only with highest quantity you can use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` clause in following:

**QUERY**

```
select [date], [description], pdv, id, name, value, 
       max(case when rn > 1 then quantity +rn-1 else quantity end) as quantity
from( 
    select *, 
           row_number() over(partition by [date], [description], pdv, id, name, value, quantity order by [date]) rn 
    from #t
)x
group by [date], [description], pdv, id, name, value
```

**OUPUT**

```
date        description pdv     id  name                value   quantity
2016-01-25  CENAS       REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  1
2016-01-25  COMIDAS     REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  1
2016-01-25  DESAYUNOS   REST    1   DEL PATRON COMBO    162.00  4
```

Comment: wow it indeed increased the quantity but the row stil inserts is there a way to just let the row with the larger quantity? like increment quantity and dont add row like in distinc

Comment: @ArturoMartinez update your question with desired output (what result you want to get).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'm going to use **GROUP BY**, please take a look at this example below

```
 SELECT  |DATE|
        ,|DESCRIPTION|
        ,|PDV|
        ,|ID|
        ,|NAME|
        ,|Value|
        ,SUM(|Quantity|)
FROM @YourTable
GROUP BY  |DATE|
         ,|DESCRIPTION|
         ,|PDV|
         ,|ID|
         ,|NAME|
         ,|Value|
```